# Angular, Web Components and Startup Performance

Tags: angular, web-component

I have created an Angular 14 project with a dependency on an [Angular element](https://angular.io/guide/elements) that was built using Angular 12. The Angular 14 app imports the web component in the normal way, namely by loading the script that is generated from the Angular 12 project (details of how can be found [here](https://github.com/maxant/angularelements/tree/main/angular12element)). The web component logs the angular version number (imported with `VERSION from @angular/core`) and prints 12.2.16. The main app does the same and prints 14.2.1.

Q1 - Is it correct to assume that every angular element which is loaded from it's own script will bootstrap the angular library which that script contains, so in this case there are two instances of Angular running in the browser (if you can say it that way)?

Q2 - If a second web component were also built with Angular 12.2.16, and were also loaded by its own script, would a third instance of Angular be started, or is Angular clever enough to know that it is already running and skip that part of the boot strapping?

Q3 - Is there anyway to tell Angular that when it builds the production code (using `ng build`) that it should not put all of the Angular code into the generated script which is used to load the web component, as this will be *provided* by the main app (similar to the [provided scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) in Maven)?

Comment: I just noticed that the version number 12.2.16 is hard coded in the generated javascript component - I'm assuming that the Typescript compiler copies that into the generated source, rather than letting it be read at runtime. So I need to find another way of determining if Angular is part of the generated Javascript. But I'm assuming it is, because the web component should be able to run without the host application running Angular.

Comment: Reading through the generated script, it is clear that all the necessary parts of Angular which the web component depends on, are in there, so when the Javascript is downloaded by the browser, it has to parse it all and is effectively reloading Angular even though the main application has already done that. Question 2 addresses the question of whether or not angular optimises this and skips a second reload, which it may well do.